# How to set types based on a value of a property in another parameter?

Tags: node.js, typescript, .d.ts

How should I set a type based on a value of a property of another parameter in a method? I'm relatively new to TypeScript.

This is what I tried:

```js
class SomeClass {
    // constructor, other properties, etc
    listen<K extends keyof ClientEvents>({ event: K }: ClientEvent, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => any)
}
```

Here, `ClientEvents` looks like this:

```js
interface ClientEvents {
    "event-1": [data: number]
    "event-2": [data: number]
    "event-3": [data: any]
}
```

And `ClientEvent` (no s) looks like this:

```js
interface ClientEvent {
    event: keyof ClientEvents
    anotherProperty: any // I don't want to share all the properties
}
```

Currently, the `event` field *does* autofill to `event-1`, but the first parameter to the function shows up as type `any`, but it should be type `number`. How can I fix this without needing more parameters?

When changing one of the `data`s from inside of `ClientEvents` to type `string`, it shows up as type `string | number`.

```js
class SomeClass {
  listen<K extends keyof ClientEvents>({ event: K }: ClientEvent, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => any): void;
}

interface ClientEvents {
  "event-1": [data: number]
  "event-2": [data: string]
}

interface ClientEvent {
  event: keyof ClientEvents
  anotherProperty: any
}

new SomeClass().listen({ 
  event: "event-1", 
  anotherProperty: 1 
}, (arg) => { 
  arg // type is string | number
})
```

Here is a [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMoHsC2IDC0q8A3gLABQ88EAlsgC4gB2APANLwgAejTwaAaxABPTADN4BGs3oBRAG4zkAPgAUxToqb0AXPA4BfPVJkKZAGmp1eIGHtUA6J7ADmyY7VNb6yANpsAXQBKeABeZXgoJmEgvXlMGmAAbgoDCgoabVsxKDAEE20zbTQySngAIhBvAFoARnK9X2Aoeig9JgBXbAAjWwCKKkqagCYG+CaWtvgGGEyXfvI08gysmBy8yU9C7xIBzRk9IVEJArlvZD2ozHoAC1sABRhMAAdbemE9KOFU9PImEAA7hgcPhCMhVEEHLQGMx1PttHohjI6uVLFdbg8nq8YO89LV4AZLKpXCFwiRIjAXASgr8gA)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but your actual problem is written in words and not code, so ‍♂️.  Please consider providing a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mx6Q1w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: @jcalz turns out that I actually changed one of the `data`s from `ClientEvents` to string there, and the type changes to `string | number` - see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMoHsC2IDC0q8A3gLABQ88EAlsgC4gB2APANLwgAejTwaAaxABPTADN4BGs3oBRAG4zkAPgAUxToqb0AXPA4BfPVJkKZAGmp1eIGHtUA6J7ADmyY7VNb6yANpsAXQBKeABeZXgoJmEgvXlMGmAAbgoDCgoabVsxKDAEE20zbTQySngAIhBvAFoARnK9X2Aoeig9JgBXbAAjWwCKKkqagCYG+CaWtvgGGEyXfvI08gysmBy8yU9C7xIBzRk9IVEJArlvZD2ozHoAC1sABRhMAAdbemE9KOFU9PImEAA7hgcPhCMhVEEHLQGMx1PttHohjI6uVLFdbg8nq8YO89LV4AZLKpXCFwiRIjAXASgr8gA)

Comment: Please put that in the question in plaintext (although a playground link as a supplement is helpful) so that others don't have to read through comments to understand what's going on.

Comment: Could you include the code with the actual problem?  The line of code that demonstrates the English text “it shows up as `string | number`.

Comment: @jcalz you mean the `new SomeClass()` part?

Comment: Indeed that, or whatever it is that demonstrates the `unknown` thing you’re talking about above.  Someone should be able to  look at the code in the question and say “yes I see” and not “where is the problem exactly”.

Comment: I see you've already answered your own question.. I would fix it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEG1Om), which is similar to yours except I'm not redefining `ClientEvent` to do it.  I wouldn't call this a "workaround", though.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer or if you're happy with your own.

Comment: @jcalz I'm not the best with TypeScript, and I was actually looking for something with `&` at first, but couldn't find a way. You can write your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the FAQ entry on destructuring assignment and type annotations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-use-x-in-the-destructuring-function-f-x-number------) for a possibly-authoritative answer.

Your problem is that the `K` in `{ event: K }: ClientEvent` isn't what you think it is.  In JavaScript, if you have a function parameter like `{ event: K }`, you are using [destructuring assignment with variable renaming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names), so you will copy the `event` property of that function argument into a **variable named `K`**:

```
function foo({event: K}: ClientEvent) {
  // variable -----> ^
  console.log(K.toUpperCase()); 
  //          ^ <---- see?      
}
foo({event: "event-1", anotherProperty: 123})  // EVENT-1
```

Because JavaScript supports this, so does TypeScript (as you can see by the `ClientEvent` [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations)), and therefore the call signature itself just uses `K` as a dummy parameter name that it ignores.

And of course, that `K` cannot be used as an inference site for the type parameter `K` of the same name, since they are unrelated.

---

You were attempting to use `K` as a *type annotation* for the `event` property.  But that's not supported.  In fact there is currently no way to put type annotations inside the destructured object itself.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) asking for some way to do this (maybe... double colon? like `{event::K}`) but for now it's impossible.

If you want to give a type to the `event` property, you will have to do it in the actual type annotation, after the destructured object:

```
{ event }: { event: K }
```

And if you want to preserve the fact that the whole thing needs to be a `ClientEvent`, you will need to express that with something like an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)

```
{ event }: { event: K } & ClientEvent
```

Or possibly by extending your `ClientEvent` interface if that looks nicer:

```
interface ClientEventFor<K extends keyof ClientEvents> extends ClientEvent {
  event: K
}

declare class SomeClass {
  listen<K extends keyof ClientEvents>(
    { event }: ClientEventFor<K>,
    listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => any): void;
}
```

And then things will start working for you:

```
new SomeClass().listen(
  { event: "event-1", anotherProperty: 1 },
  (arg) => { arg.toFixed() } // okay, arg is number here
)
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDCAbMNoCiAbvlAM7oDeo66ARDCdALQCMdAXOgNoAmSUJFwgBXALYAjeAF0a9RqWYAmTj36CuZKHEgBzWSFoMmUZgGZVfAUPQSA9newwkEAwF9QkWIlQYceQhMqOQVoLgBrGABPOwQsXFJiUjI5FzsoAAt4AAU4OwAHeCgorhco0A8QT2h4ZDR4gKgk6AAxOzgAHgBpdBgAD1gIXgpImLj-RJMyAD5egfxhhsnSYMNeky4uitBQXhgUbCQ4DAOkMgoAZTsxGBwzimo13C18brnBxdHYpcDk6YAKOS0SjrFZuLgTX6tdrdaYAGiB6Geg3gXH+ADpMUddGQIQkoeRuF1pABKdAAXlmZRJXCIdjAvAA3NsqiAIDAAO7oK43O7nf4k9HI-CAtYg0JQLjGRTsOHoNKZHJ5QpwYpcVjoNwItb-bFkylUeVwXToqB2FpgPowXgCzXoAD09vQdnCSCicux6DAFFEkng6Cyx1AJJ2ICAA)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround using type parameters in the interface

```
export interface ClientEvent<L = keyof ClientEvents> {
    event: L,
    site: string
}

export class SomeClass {
    listen<K extends keyof ClientEvents>({ event }: ClientEvent<K>, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => any): SomeClass
}
```

And the JavaScript code:

```js
let a = new Client()
a.listen({
    event: "event-2"
}, (a) => {
    a
})
```

Says `a` is a string, so it works perfectly.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMoHsC2IDC0q8A3gLABQ88EAlsgC4gB2APANLwgAejTwaAaxABPTADN4BGs3oBRAG4zkAPgAUxToqb14AXwBck2jIUz2ygDTU6vEDEOqAdM9gBzZIakmt9ZAG02AF0ASngAXmV4KCZhYMN5TBpgAG4KXQoKGm07MSgwBC9tU200Mkp4ACIQHwBaAEYKwz9gKHooQyYAV2wAIztAiioq2oAmRvhm1vb4Bhgs1wHydPJM7Jhc-KNpIp8WABlw+CFRCUK5HxUSQc0ZQz3r6Mx6AAs7AAUYTAAHO3phQ2iwjSGXITBAAHcMDh8IRkKpgo5aAxmOobtpDMMZPUKlZHi93p8fjA-oY6norKo3KEIiQojBXHpghQAPTMukMuhReBdXp2ChAA)