# How to use properties in passed array's values as the type for another parameter in a class?

Tags: typescript

Here's an example of what I want to achieve (check the comment):

```
class Test {
    constructor(
        public options: {
            entries: { name: string }[];
            handler: (entryName: string) => void;
        }
    ) {}
}

const test = new Test({
    entries: [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }],
    handler(name) {
        // `name` should be "a" | "b" | "c"
    },
});
```

I tried a bunch of stuff with type parameters and `extends`, also tried using `infer`.

I asked Chat GPT and it told me:

> In TypeScript, you cannot directly derive a type for the handler function parameter based on the name property of objects in an array within the same interface because TypeScript's type system does not support this level of dynamism directly within object type definitions. TypeScript's type system operates at compile time and doesn't have the capability to infer a union type from an instance's property values.

Is this true? Is it really not possible? I think I've seen this behavior before when using certain libraries, but I can't recall any of them now.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789912/how-to-set-types-based-on-a-value-of-a-property-in-another-parameter) looks similar, but it's about using the keys of a predefined interface. In my case, the keys are dynamic, based on what you pass: `entries: [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }]`

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNH1gHsA7ZAJwFdgl8SAKLXB6ABzICMQBLYafJpDohABcaeo3HxCSEh0QjU0QmAC28EaQ6EA5tAC+AbQC6AbjHiGACzCEAJiHgkRNSdICeAORVroG7QEpoAF4APmgAN3wOG1Nsc10zaADUeMwUrAJiFCREFEDFeAB3OByaDFicFxk5aH0FJVURACIwRr0AGjRFLybWVt0Ouu7oRuA+wzaEq1t7Wnr4JISGAHol6AADObWfC3wyEBtoVnhhlugAH2He8+HRxdwMiHx7ADoQfC0aOb8Yhn6sXW+QA) for the code above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you can add type variables:

```
class Test<N extends string> {
    constructor(
        public options: {
            entries: { name: N }[];
            handler: (entryName: N) => void;
        }
    ) {}
}

const test = new Test({
    entries: [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }],
    handler(name) {
        // `name` should be "a" | "b" | "c"
        console.log(name);
    },
});
```

Here's [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuAeYB7Ads6A5a8AHkvJgCYzIBOAlpgOYB80A3gLABQ030G2SVAK7Ak6KgApOPadAAOggEYgawaOllIaWCAC5WUmYdICaiPS2iYwAW3h78AXwDaAXQDcBw9IAWYciHgqPXFjKgBPXBs7PABKaABeZgA3dBoyDy4vB09oOJZsjgLOPhwSHHjLeAB3OEQkcXZM7lDTXWgnCytbPQAiMB7oBwAaVkso3oUB4dGu6J7gKZchnN9-QPFZvJzpAHod6AADWYPoCG90QRAyaAV4aD6BgB97yehn+Z7tnhL0AIA6EDoegbKIxDLSYacBxgzhAA)

Comment: Yep, that does it! I tried way more complicated things than that, for some reason…